# How do I install to my Linux laptop a software project hosted on git?

Tags: linux, git

How do I install, to my Linux laptop, a software project hosted on GitHub? I am not attempting to set up a project/repository myself. My intention is to download a project, in order to use/execute it. What is the name of this process? How is it done? If it helps, I am trying to install the command line interface for Last Pass. Their instructions seem to only assist me with downloading the dependencies. Downloading the zip file just provides a folder filed with random files. I am used to installers, so perhaps I am missing some steps that would aid my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not about programming. It also has nothing to do with git, you just got the files from github, but git has nothing to do with installing it.

The first thing you should do is check if the software is available already from your Linux distribution, using the system's software management tools. Installing it from there will be simpler and will mean the software gets updated automatically in future.

If it isn't packaged by your distro, and the project don't provide binaries, then you may need to build the software yourself. Among the files you cloned from github should be a README or INSTALL file with instructions on building and installing it.

Typically this involves running a `configure` script, or maybe `cmake`, to set up the build process correctly for your computer, then running `make` and `make install`.

Depending whether you want to install it just for your user or system-wide you might need to run the configuration step with an option specifying where to install to.

Depending on the programming language used you might need to install some additional tools, such as a compiler and linker. These will definitely be available from your distro's software management tool.

Comment: I appreciate the prompt response. Thank you.